# Connect two php variables

Tags: php, html

Im getting text & color from a form like this:

**Codes in *management.php* :**

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="color" name="color">
   <input type="text" name="text">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   <?php
   $color = $_POST['color']; 
   $text = $_POST['text'];
   ?>
</form>
```

and now i want to use these variables in another file named *index.php*

**Codes in *index.php* :**

```
<?php
echo ' <p style="color: ' . $color . ';"> ' . $text . ' </p> ';
?>
```

How Can I get only variables from other php files?

Comment: You can use `session` for it.

Comment: Input type color isn't supported in IE, it's recommend to use an alternative for IE.

Comment: Define them in a file called `colors.php`, and `include('colors.php');` in both `index.php` and in `management.php`

Comment: @Daan Is `IE` still exist!!! Which year I am in :P

Comment: @Parixit - yes, IE still exists, currently at version 11 which was released on October 17th, 2013..... it's really quite common for software to go through version updates periodically, rather than simply ceasing to exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by storing values into `SESSION` variable like this :

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="color" name="color">
   <input type="text" name="text">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

   <?php
       $_SESSION['color'] = $_POST['color']; 
       $_SESSION['text'] = $_POST['text'];
   ?>
```

And you can use it in other files like this :

```
<?php
    echo '<p style="color: '.$_SESSION['color'].';"> '.$_SESSION['text'].'</p>';
?>
```

You need to put `session_start()` at the beginning of all your files where you want to use `SESSION`

And I join what `Daan` says in comment, input of type `color` is not supported in IE you should use another thing.

Comment: You forgot to start the session.

Comment: @Daan Oh yes ! Thank you ^^

Comment: thnx, and when these variables die? if I use them and set hello as text with white color then whenever I open index.php do I see a "hello" with white color?

Comment: These variables dies if you use `session_destroy()` or if you use `unset($_SESSION['text'])` and when you close your web browser

Answer (score 2):

If it is .php extension file oyu can use below

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <input type="color" name="color" values="<?php echo $_POST['color'];?>">
   <input type="text" name="text" values="<?php echo $_POST['text']; ?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: And how exactly will `$color` and `$text` be defined in index.php ?

Comment: @Daan Its $_POST only right? I hope he is submitting this to current form page from other page with some POST values

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save those values for future use you should create a file and store the values. In every file where you need these values you use the `include();` command to load the saved file.

If you only want to use them for this session you could store the values in a session and put the `session_start();` command at the top of every file you need these values with.

If you just want to see how form values can be used in another file (one time use) you could change your files to:

**management.php**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
   <input type="color" name="color">
   <input type="text" name="text">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

    $color = $_POST['color']; 
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    echo ' <p style="color: ' . $color . ';"> ' . $text . ' </p> ';
?>
```

Always perform validation checks on submitted values and take note of what others mentioned about options that are not available for all browsers.