# Store variables on a php file

Tags: php, html

I want to get some variables from an html form in a file named ***management.php*** and store variables in another php file named ***vars.php***, and then use those variables by including them in other php files.

So I wrote these codes in **management.php**:

```
<form method="post" action="vars.php">
  <input type="text" name="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And these codes in **vars.php**:

```
  <?php 
    $text = $_POST['text']; 
  ?>
```

And then use these variables in some other file like **index.html**:

```
<?php
include 'vars.php';
echo $text;
?>
```

But its not working...
I get below error:

> Notice: Undefined index: text in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vars.php on line
>   10

Im pretty new with php , please help me with this.

Comment: You already asked a similar question today with good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174845/connect-two-php-variables

Comment: You need to either use a session, cookie or a database. PHP variables aren't "stored" like that, if you change page / reload / etc etc. the variables will be empty unless you set them again.

Comment: @Daan No, Its not same. I want to store them in other files & use them for future. session is not what i am looking for.

Comment: @AliSeyfi, Use session or try to return that value in that page. Also you can use ajax or javascript for this.

Comment: For solve your problem you can use `cookies`

Comment: @ms-nehal I want to make a management panel for some one to be able to edit the webpage and the edit remain for future. I dont think javascript work.

Comment: Show us, how you make your `vars.php` file. Also, I'd like to see, how you handle user input. Also, I suppose, you make something bad with your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store variables into a file but you can store it into `session` or `cookie`

**With a Session**

To do this you first need to add this line in each php file you use :

```
session_start();
```

Then, you can store in `SESSION` variables like this :

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['color'] = $_POST['color']; 
    $_SESSION['text'] = $_POST['text']; 
?>
```

And you can use it in another files like this :

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['color'];
?>
```

**With a Cookie**

But if you want to use it in another visit on your website you should use `cookie` like this :

```
<?php
     setcookie('text',$_POST['text']);
     setcookie('color',$_POST['color']);
?>
```

And use it like this from any php file of your website :

```
<?php
    echo $_COOKIE['text'];
    echo $_COOKIE['color'];
?>
```

**Notice :**

The datas will not store into a file on your server but in the client computer.

If the client restore his computer, variables will diseapear.

Comment: Thanx, but  I want to make a management panel for some one to be able to edit the webpage and the edit remain for future.session wont remain for future does Cokkie remain?

Comment: Cookie will remain but for each user separately. If you want to store them for all users, you need to use a database.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do like that. On form submit in var.php $_POST['text'] get value from form. but using "include 'var.php';" $text will try to find $_POST['text'] value. So it shows "Undefined index" error.

To do this **without using session** you can do like

1. In var.php

   <?php

   ```
   $content = '<?php $text="' .$_POST['text'] . '";  ?>';

   file_put_contents('./path/variables.php', $content );
   ```

   ?>
2. In index.html

   <?php

   ```
   include './path/variables.php';

   echo $text;
   ```

   ?>

Here, I have created a new php file and save the variable then used it.

Answer (score -1):

html file not be able to read php file so you got the error. Give the php file name in form action.it will be work.

Comment: Static HTML files also does not report PHP errors! Since the op receives a PHP Notice it means that the HTML file is run through the PHP interpreter. There is no need to change its extension.

Comment: it not give the php error it give not found error because it wont be able to read it.

Comment: Where are you seeing the "Not found" part? He's clearing having a "Notice..." error.